# Core dump to a pipe is failing

Tags: linux, pipe, mips, coredump

Tried this on MIPS platform:

```
> uname -a
Linux (none) 2.6.29 #2 Mon Jan 14 13:26:04 PST 2013 mips GNU/Linux
> ulimit -c unlimited
> which gzip
/bin/gzip
> echo "|/bin/gzip - > /home/core-%t-%s-%e.gz" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
> ./fault
hello there
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ls /home/core*.gz
ls: /home/core*: No such file or directory
```

i.e. piping to a program doesn't work. if I specify a file:

```
> echo "/home/core-%t-%s-%e" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

then it works. What did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps it fail because the kernel doesn't run any shell, but try to execute a program.
Try to wrap the gzip invocation with the redirection in a script and use that script.

Comment: Your solution is right but not for the reason you have mentioned. See here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4871150#post4871150

Comment: that's the exact reason. `>` is shell language for redirecting standard output to a file, which is not interpreted by the kernel when trying to execute the program mentioned in core_pattern. (This work in a interactive shell or a shell script)

Answer (score 1):

It's solved here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4871150#post4871150
Thanks to [millgates](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/user/millgates-456235/) and [ydroneaud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611560/ydroneaud)!

Comment: An answer should include enough information to solve the problem, valid even if the link breaks.

Comment: See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really good answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved Eric's answer:

```
sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern='|/bin/sh -c $@ -- eval exec gzip --fast > /var/crash/core-%e.%p.gz'
```

No need for the shell to be saved a separate file indeed. Checked on CentOS-7.7.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and should be the accepted answer. Not everyone has the capability of wrapping in a separate script.

```
echo "|/bin/bash -c \"\$@\" -- eval gzip > /tme/core.%E.%p.%t.gz" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Comment: I agree with the `|/bin/bash -c`, but not with structuring the commands to use `eval` unnecessarily. Consider `bash -c '"$@" > "$0"' /tme/core.%E.%p.%t.gz gzip` -- that way there's no need for `eval` and its associated risks.

Comment: BTW, "should be the accepted answer" is perhaps not good form -- that's for the OP to decide, just as upvotes/downvotes are up to the community as a whole. Completely legitimate to point out the advantages of an approach; gratuitous to make value judgments on those advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrapping in a script didn't work for me, I also had to specify proper shell environment in core.sh

```
root@fredy:/data/cores# cat /usr/local/sbin/core.sh
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/pigz -f - >"/data/cores/core-$1-$2-$3-$4-$5.gz"
```

and

```
root@fredy:/data/cores# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/local/sbin/core.sh %e %p %h %s %t
```